# Integer sequence that "fills a range in a balanced way"

Tags: sequences-and-series, integers, music-theory

I am writing a piece of software to generate musical sequences, and I would like a way to slowly introduce notes in a chord in a balanced way across the range of the chord. I want it to be more interesting and sonically balanced than top to bottom, or stepwise.

I am looking for a sequence that subdivides a range of integers recursively.

For example, something similar to, or the same as:

For the range 1-8, generate the sequence: 4,8,2,6,3,7,1,5.

For 1-7, generate the sequence: 3,7,1,5,2,6,4

For 1-6, generate the sequence: 3,6,1,4,2,5

For 1-32: 16,32,8,24,12,28,4,20,14,30,6,22,10,26,2,18,15,31,7,23,11,27,3,19,13,29,5,21,9,25,1,17

This sequence cuts the range in half (rounding down) and records the maximum of each subdivision. It repeats, visiting the subdivisions in a balanced way.  An important detail is that it doesn't just visit the subdivisions in a linear way (left to right), but in some form of symmetrical hopping.

Are there any functions or algorithms that are similar to this?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you're asking. Can you provide more examples for the range $1$-$n$ with varying values of $n$? For the range $1,2,\dots,7$ for example, what is the sequence you are expecting?

Comment: @YiFan I've updated the question body.

Comment: It seems from your example you need to figure how to generate 4,2,3,1 from, 8, how to generate 3,1,2,(4) from 7, and how to generate 3,1,2 from 6. (Then if $n$ is even you add $n/2$ and if $n$ is odd $(n+1)/2$ to each of the numbers already generated, e,g, for 8 we get 4,4+4,2,2+4,3,3+4,1,1+4). Welcome to MSE! For 8, you seem to start with 4, then go down with step 2 till no longer possible, get 4,2, then decrease these numbers with 1, get 3,1, so total, 4,2,3,1. The other examples look similar. I wonder if you would always want to decrease with step 2, or perhaps with a larger step, for 1-16?

Comment: The fractional parts of multiples of the golden ratio form a nice equidistributed sequence, see e.g. "[Why is the Golden section the "best" arrangement?](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibnat2.html)". Take $n$ of them and use their ordering as the output sequence. E.g. the first $8$ are $0.618, 0.236, 0.854, 0.472, 0.090, 0.708, 0.326, 0.944$; here $0.618$ is the fifth smallest, $0.236$ is the second smallest, and so on, so the sequence is $5, 2, 7, 4, 1, 6, 3, 8$.

Comment: @Rahul thank you, that's awesome!